# Damaged USB after using RUFUS

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I made a bootable Linux USB . Everything works fine after the install i tried to reuse my usb to copy some files. Size of the USB is now 4mb "EFI partition".
I jumped to DISKPART to clean and set partition :

```
 Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.22000.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: XXXXXXX

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online         1863 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Online           15 GB  1024 KB

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart has encountered an error: A device which does not exist was specified.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART>
```

[Tried with Disk management in windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iU3p.png)

Comment: What error was shown in the System Event Log ?

Comment: @Silbee : I just fixed it. Check my comment below. Thank you for your time  ♥

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who have problems after using Rufus .
Re-open Rufus , connect your usb drive , select your usb drive and select
`Non Bootable` in `Boot selection` .
This fixed my problem.

Comment: Note there is literally an [entry for that](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_how_do_I_restore_my_USB_to_how_it_was_before_I_created_a_bootable_drive) in the Rufus application FAQ. Also be mindful that it's not because Windows only shows a small partition that the drive is "damaged".

Answer (score 0):

Please install PowerISO (https://www.poweriso.com/) software, then connect your USB and open PowerISO. Choose Tools >> Clean USB option. It will format your USB as FAT32. After that format your USB manually choosing NTFS format. Everything will be fine.